# Чи є різниця між "оснований" та "заснований"?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

Згідно до СУМу - слова "оснований" та "заснований" можуть бути синонімами, це ж стосується і слів від яких вони походять:

> Дальшим кроком в розвою театрального діла у нас єсть.. думка Лавровського — **оснувати** у Львові постійну руську сцену (Іван Франко, XVI, 1955, 104)
>
> Року 1890 він [І. Франко], вкупі з другими, **засновує** радикальну партію, став на її чолі (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 35)

Однак у цій [статті](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21176) ідеться про те, що це різні слова і даються аргументи: "оснований" відповідає на питання "на чому?" та має лише значення "той, що базується на чомусь, в основі якого лежить те, про що йдеться", а слово "заснований" відповідає на питання "ким? де? коли?" і означає "створений" чи "розпочатий".

Отож, то як бути з цими словами і чи справді їх не можна вживати як синоніми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Визначення дієслів, від яких походять дієприкметники взяті із **ВТС**.

> **[Засновувати](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53399/876239.html)**  I -ую, -уєш, недок. , заснувати, -ую, -уєш, док. ,
>   перех.
>     1. Започатковувати існування чого-небудь, створювати,
>   організовувати щось.
>
> 2. на чому. Будувати, створювати на основі чого-небудь, виходячи з
>      чогось.
>
> II -ую, -уєш, недок. , **заснувати**, -ую, -уєш, док. , перех.
>
> 1. Снуючи нитки, робити основу тканини. || перен. Покривати,
>      затягувати щось чим-небудь.
> 2. перен. Наповнювати, оповивати, огортати і т. ін. що-небудь. ||
>      безос.
>
> **[Основувати](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53406/931330.html)** 
>   -ую, -уєш, недок. , оснувати, -ую, -уєш, док. , перех.  1. Те саме, що обсновувати.
>
> 2. Робити з пряжі основу.
> 3. *заст*. **Засновувати.**
> 4. на чому, рідко. Ґрунтувати, базувати.

**[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)**

> ЗАСНО́ВУВАТИ (будуючи щось, поселяючись десь, класти початок існуванню
>   чого-небудь), ЗАКЛАДА́ТИ, ФУНДУВА́ТИ, ПОЧИНА́ТИ рідше, **ОСНО́ВУВАТИ**
>   *заст*., ОСА́ДЖУВАТИ перев. док., заст. - Док.: заснува́ти, закла́сти, поча́ти, оснува́ти, осади́ти

Звісно, як видно із словника синонімів, ми можемо використовувати їх як синоніми. На мою думку, дані слова не можна назвати повними синонімами, адже вони не відповідають один одному по всіх значеннях. Отже і похідні від них *"оснований"* та *"заснований"* не будуть повними синонімами, тому використовувати їх потрібно обережно.